# Sxa sort by relevance does a random sorting of search results in absence of search term

Tags: sxa, sxa-search, search-facet

I am using `Sxa Sort by relevance` in search results and the `facet` is based on the `title`. This is used in such a way that it defaults to `relevance` on the site. Additionally used a boosting feature on the title as well.

[image]
[image]

[image]

But the issue is when there is no search term, then it does a `random sorting` on the search results.
Is there a way to avoid this random sorting & change it to organized sort?

Comment: Check this https://www.maartenwillebrands.nl/2021/05/10/sxa-sort-by-title-does-not-work/